# Periodically synchronise databases on 2 different servers

Tags: sql-server, replication, data-synchronization

On my main development workstation I have around 20 databases. Every so often I will work from home on my laptop instead, where I also need a copy of these databases. Because working from home is fairly infrequent, the databases are often a long way behind my main development databases on my workstation.

Currently what I do is take a backup of the workstation database, and then restore it on my laptop, but this is becoming time-consuming. Especially since some software projects require multiple databases.

Is there a more automated way of achieving database synchronisation between my main workstation and my laptop?

Would something like replication come with its own problems? Ideally I want it as automated as possible.

Comment: What about source control and synchronizing schema changes? I kinda have the same issue going on and this gives me a good idea for a project.

Comment: Good suggestion. I already do that using the data tools. The schema is not an issue as I use SSDT to publish out those changes from source control seamlessly. The project in question has dependent databases though, which can (and do) change in isolation from the project. These are the ones I am looking to seamlessly sync.

Comment: Which part of the backup & restore is time-consuming? Your effort to do it, or moving the bits? If the former, that's easily remedied via scripting.

Comment: @alroc the main issue is moving the backups between two machines over the web - this is always time-consuming and slow.

Comment: "Moving across the web"? Why not copy them to your desktop before you leave the office?